# int to string to date

Tags: asp.net, datetime

i use asp.net

i have a int  (10112009)

in the end i want a date formate like day- day / month month / yyyy

what's the best way (or a way) to do that?

thanks

Comment: Will it always be 8 characters long? i.e. How will the first of the month be represented, 1112009 or 01112009? As you've said it's being stored as an Int, I'd assume the first one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
int n = 10112009;
DateTime date;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(n.ToString("00000000"), "ddMMyyyy", 
        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out date))
{
    // use date
}
```